# How to popViewController from button click of custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a button in a custom UITableViewCell. Its UITableView is controlled by a UIViewController. I would like to return to the RootView when that button is clicked.

I am trying to use
    [self.superview.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
in the target Action of the button, which is in the UITableViewCell.m file. However, it doesn't recognize "navigationController" because it is not in the stack.

How can I return to the RootView when that button is clicked?

Answer (score 5):

Views have no explicit relation to controllers and views cannot be in the controller stack.  Set the button target to be a UIViewController instance and in the action method call:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES|NO];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the strange wording, I'm a noob. I don't understand how to "Set the button target to be a UIViewController instance".

Comment: You have a UIViewController that controls the UITableView and is probably the delegate.  When you create the button, set the target to be that UIViewController.  If the target is being set in a xib, set it to the controller of the table.

Comment: if you got it working,you should probably accept the answer :)